# Can someone find the bug in my code for Matrix Rotation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, matrix

I'm trying to do the hackerrank Matrix Rotation challenge. My code has a bug in it somewhere that I can't find. The code is supposed to rotate all the outer and inner loops of test matrices r number of times (1 <= r <= 10 E 9). If I don't do a modulus on r the code runs fine except for the higher values values of r where it times out on the hackerrank server. If I do a modulus on r then the code fails the test cases where r >= (r % number_of _elements_in_outer_loop). I can't find the bug. Thanks in advance for any replies. Following is the code (testing in Visual Studio 2015). The hackerrank challenge with the requirements is [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo)

```
// MatrixRotation.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//  int i, j, k;
    int m, n, r;
    int rotations, rot;
    int m_start, m_end, m_len;
    int n_start, n_end, n_len;
    int m_curr, n_curr;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For hackerrank testing
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {

        if (i == 1) std::cin >> m;
        else if (i == 2) std::cin >> n;
        else std::cin >> r;

    }

    int **matrix = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cin >> matrix[i][j];


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // For local machine in Visual Studio testing
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*

    int i, j, k;

    m = 10;
    n = 8;
    r = 40;

    int **matrix = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new int[n];
    }

    k = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = k;
            k += 1;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";

            if (j == n - 1)
                std::cout << endl;

        }

    std::cout << endl;

    */

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Begin computations
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int outer_loop_rotation;

    outer_loop_rotation = (n - 1)  + (m - 1) + (n - 1) + (m - 1)  ;

    rot = r % outer_loop_rotation;

//  std::cout << endl << endl << "outer loop rotation = " << outer_loop_rotation << endl << endl << "rot = " << rot << endl << endl;

    for (rotations = 1; rotations <= rot; rotations++)
    {

        m_start = 0;
        m_end = m - 1;

        n_start = 0;
        n_end = n - 1;

        m_len = m_end - m_start;
        n_len = n_end - n_start;


        // Following while loop is 1 rotation for all loops

        while (m_len >= 1 && n_len >= 1)
        {

            int loop_start = matrix[m_start][n_start];

            // Following for loop is for row start

            m_curr = m_start;
            n_curr = n_start;

            for (i = 1; i <= n_len  ; i++)
            {

                matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr][n_curr + 1];
                n_curr += 1;

            }

            // Following for loop is for col end

            m_curr = m_start;
            n_curr = n_end;

            for (i = 1; i <= m_len  ; i++)
            {

                matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr + 1][n_curr];
                m_curr += 1;

            }

            // Following for loop is for row end

            m_curr = m_end;
            n_curr = n_end;

            for (i = 1; i <= n_len  ; i++)
            {

                matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr][n_curr - 1];
                n_curr -= 1;

            }

            // Following for loop is for col start

            m_curr = m_end;
            n_curr = n_start;

            for (i = 1; i <= m_len   ; i++)
            {
                if (i < m_len )
                {
                    matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr - 1][n_curr];
                    m_curr -= 1;


                }

                else
                {

                    matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = loop_start;


                }

            }

            m_start += 1;
            m_end -= 1;

            n_start += 1;
            n_end -= 1;

            m_len = m_end - m_start;
            n_len = n_end - n_start;


        } // End while loop

    } // End for loop

    // End computations, now output to command line

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";

            if (j == n - 1)
                std::cout << endl;

        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hackerrank challenge link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo/copy-from/13133234 If you run my code in the challenge then you have to comment out #include "stdafx.h" at the beginning of the code.

Comment: You should rotate each loop by r positions, or after the optimisation, `r % number_of_positions_in_this_loop` positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bug is that you are computing a modulus value only once for the whole matrix, corresponding to the cycle repeat length of rotating the outermost layer. However, each layer in the matrix is going to have a different cycle length. For example, the repeat cycle length of the outermost layer, as you are calculating it, is:

```
(n - 1)  + (m - 1) + (n - 1) + (m - 1)
```

However, for the second-to-outermost layer, the repeat length is:

```
(n - 3)  + (m - 3) + (n - 3) + (m - 3)
```

or more generally

```
((n - ((layer*2)+1))  + (m - ((layer*2)+1))) * 2
```

where the outermost layer is 0, the second-to-outermost is 1 etc.

So, you need to change your code to compute the modulus for each layer instead of once for the whole matrix.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking but I wasn't sure. If it works I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I had to swap the outer "for" and "while" loops to make it work. I will mark your answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final code that worked, in case anyone is interested.

```
  // MatrixRotation.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
  //

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//  int i, j, k;
    int m, n, r;
    int rotations, rot;
    int loop_decrement, loop_rotation;
    int m_start, m_end, m_len;
    int n_start, n_end, n_len;
    int m_curr, n_curr;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For hackerrank testing
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {

        if (i == 1) std::cin >> m;
        else if (i == 2) std::cin >> n;
        else std::cin >> r;

    }

    int **matrix = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cin >> matrix[i][j];


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // For local machine in Visual Studio testing
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*  

    int i, j, k;

    m = 4;
    n = 4;
    r = 2;

    int **matrix = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new int[n];
    }

    k = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = k;
            k += 1;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";

            if (j == n - 1)
                std::cout << endl;

        }

    std::cout << endl;

    */

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Begin computations
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    m_start = 0;
    m_end = m - 1;

    n_start = 0;
    n_end = n - 1;

    m_len = m_end - m_start;
    n_len = n_end - n_start;


    // Following while loop is all rotations
    // for all loops one loop at a time

    loop_decrement = 1;

    while (m_len >= 1 && n_len >= 1)
    {
        // loop_rotation = number of items in current loop

        loop_rotation = (n - loop_decrement) + (m - loop_decrement) + (n - loop_decrement) + (m - loop_decrement);

        rot = r % loop_rotation;

        for (rotations = 1; rotations <= rot; rotations++)
        {

            int loop_start = matrix[m_start][n_start];

            // Following for loop is for top row in current loop

            m_curr = m_start;
            n_curr = n_start;

            for (i = 1; i <= n_len  ; i++)
            {

                matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr][n_curr + 1];
                n_curr += 1;

            }

            // Following for loop is for right col in current loop

            m_curr = m_start;
            n_curr = n_end;

            for (i = 1; i <= m_len  ; i++)
            {

                matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr + 1][n_curr];
                m_curr += 1;

            }

            // Following for loop is for bottom row in current loop

            m_curr = m_end;
            n_curr = n_end;

            for (i = 1; i <= n_len  ; i++)
            {

                matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr][n_curr - 1];
                n_curr -= 1;

            }

            // Following for loop is for left col in current loop

            m_curr = m_end;
            n_curr = n_start;

            for (i = 1; i <= m_len   ; i++)
            {
                if (i < m_len )
                {
                    matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = matrix[m_curr - 1][n_curr];
                    m_curr -= 1;


                }

                else
                {

                    matrix[m_curr][n_curr] = loop_start;


                }

            }

        } // End for loop

        m_start += 1;
        m_end -= 1;

        n_start += 1;
        n_end -= 1;

        m_len = m_end - m_start;
        n_len = n_end - n_start;

        loop_decrement += 2;

    } // End while loop

    // End computations, now output to command line

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";

            if (j == n - 1)
                std::cout << endl;

        }


    return 0;
}
```